# Whereas usage in comparison

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

Is the usage of "whereas" correct?

As far as I know is that I should use complete clause after "whereas" it's similar to "but" in usage However , "whereas" introduce a contrasting ideas. I am not asking for proofreading, I am asking if "whereas" make sense in the two examples sentences.

> The US consumption of fast food was twice as high as France's, **whereas** Italy made up 12% of fast food consumption.
>
> The US consumption of soft drinks was twice as high as France's at 15% , **whereas** Italy was the least consumption country at about 4%.

Comment: I don't think it's very natural. ***Whereas*** means ***in contrast to which***, but juxtaposing "three times higher" (than another country) and "12%" (of the global total) looks to me like comparing apples and oranges. I have no idea whether France's share of the global total is more or less than Italy's based on the text alone. But if France accounts for *more* than 12%, that implies those three countries account for over 60% of the global total. Which doesn't leave much for the rest of Europe, let alone the rest of the *world*!

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. I don't know what you mean but I think ( whereas) used to compare between two things , not three as I mentioned. I should say :

The US's consumption of fast food was 25% , whereas Italy's fast food consumption was only 7%. I just compared between two things.

Comment: Like I said, I don't find the cited usage natural. I can't tell what is being contrasted or why, and the fact that *I as a native Anglophone* can't even tell which of France or Italy has the higher value should make it obvious the text doesn't communicate anything very well.

Comment: Simplifying, what you're saying there is *X is three times bigger than Y, **in contrast to which** Z equals 12.* Which imho isn't a meaningful "contrast". It certainly gives no clue as to whether Z is bigger or smaller than Y.

Comment: An example where *whereas* does make sense is *Canada and India consume 7 and 9 percent of global ice cream production, respectively, **whereas** Switzerland gobbles up a whopping 62 percent*.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. I added another example I compared between US and France then mention that Italy is the least consumption country. Hope the example sentence is clear.

Comment: Your revised version has many shortcomings. We usually use the "noun adjunct" format ***US consumption** [of X]* rather than the possessive, and it's almost always ***twice as high as*** rather than ***two times higher than***. And I can't tell whether 25% represents the US or French total. Nor is it obvious exactly what these percentages actually refer to (Volume of liquid consumed? Number of sales? Value of sales? For all soft drink manufacturers, or just exporting American / global companies?). Whatever - to my mind, if you wouldn't use ***but***, you shouldn't use ***whereas*** either.

Comment: This is a proofreading request, so I've closed it for now as off-topic. If your goal is to learn about the usage of "whereas", please [edit] your question to tell us what you do understand about "whereas", and what you're unsure about. You can use the sentences you're trying to write as examples. Tag me in a comment and I'll be happy to reopen it and maybe even answer. (However, if your main goal is to get your sentences corrected, unfortunately, we don't do that here, so this isn't the correct site for this question.)

Comment: @gotube I edited the question. My understanding is that ( but ) usually apply to show contrast while ( whereas) Is more formal . Why should I use ( but) not ( whereas) I am here to learn.